# Show only checked values using popup in table

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

[image]

I have no idea, is there any ways to show only selected or checked attributes in a table?

Comment: yes there is :)

Comment: Please restructure and elaborate your question for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it depends on how you are saving the data, would you have an example?

Comment: Hi,I have lot of data in a table I need to display all of them but user should have an option to select which data should be displayed in the user view I couldn't  find any examples